# nginx named locations and expires header

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My nginx reverse proxy configuration has two locations with different `expires` settings:

```
location ~ ^/(admin|login|search) {
    uwsgi_pass      myproject;
    include         uwsgi_params;
    expires -1;
    uwsgi_cache off;
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass      myproject;
    include         uwsgi_params;
    expires 7d;
}
```

The `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers are set as expected. When I try to streamline this setup with a named location like this –

```
location @uwsgi {
    uwsgi_pass      myproject;
    include         uwsgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/(admin|login|search) {
    expires -1;
    uwsgi_cache off;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
}

location / {
    expires 7d;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
}
```

– the headers are not added for any response. I assume this has something to do with the redirect nature of `try_files`. Is there a way to achieve the effect of my original configuration with a named location as described above?

Comment: for which location block do you want to use it? currently it's only on the first, if all should have it, use the server block

Comment: I want to use `expires` in each block, with different values, as in my example – but it doesn't work in connection with the named location and `try_files`.

Comment: aslong as you hide the domain, we cant verify from outside, have you done some research to verify, that not your pc is using cached responses? i.e. https://httpstatus.io/ could help or similar sites

Comment: I test the configuration with `curl -I $url`. The headers are added in my original configuration (without the @uwsgi location), but they are not present in the second configuration. The difference is reproducible: Every time I switch the config and restart nginx, the headers appear/disappear.

Comment: did you restart/reload the configuration after the change, or can you do it one more times to verify the Situation

Comment: Nginx uses directives from last location. In your case it's named location and there is no `expires` directive and nginx doesn't care how you have end up there.

Comment: BTW, You first configuration is simple, clear and straightforward, while second is complicated and errorprone (and as we see hard to understand and maintain). So, just keep first configuration and do not overcomplcate things.

Comment: @AlexeyTen You are probably right.

Comment: @djdomi Alexey provided the explanation I was looking for (i.e. that the `expires` directive is not applied before the redirect to the named location). Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

No need to over-complicate things. You could make your first config one line shorter by moving `include uwsgi_params` to server block:

```
include         uwsgi_params;

location ~ ^/(admin|login|search) {
    uwsgi_pass myproject;
    expires -1;
    uwsgi_cache off;
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass myproject;
    expires 7d;
}
```

But keep in mind that if you would want to use `uwsgi_param` directive in some `location` the included directives will be skipped and you'll have to include them explicitly like this:

```
...
location /custom/ {
    uwsgi_pass myproject;
    uwsgi_param my-custom-param 42;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

so, in the end, maybe it would be easier just always use `include uwsgi_params` in all `location`s.